# How to implement per partition polling with the KafkaConsumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to consume from Kafka on a per-partition basis. I am using the `KafkaConsumer` api to do this. I see that there is a `pause` and `resume` method provided, and from the docs I can gather that this is the behaviour I want.

> Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using resume(Collection). Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used.

What I am concerned about is that I am not going to be pausing and resuming the `KafkaConsumer` intermittently, but rather I will be pausing all the partitions except the one I want to consume from. I am worried that the call to pause is expensive and will cause issues with throughput.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to implement per-partition consumption from the `KafkaConsumer` so any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to consume from a specific partition?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assign` method of `KafkaConsumer` class to specify partitions you want to consume from. `Pause` and `resume` methods take a collection of partitions as a parameter, so you can  pause or resume a specific set of partitions.

Comment: Is pausing an expensive operation? Is it bad if  I pause and unpause a partition in quick succession?

Comment: It is not expensive, but you'd better describe the problem you are trying to solve. Probably there is another solution.